# share Code between two JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've the following (Using MVC5 Project) code which I need to use in two different JS files.
What is the best way to do that ?

```
$("#act").prop("disabled", "disabled");
$("form").change(function () { 
    $("#act").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#btn").prop("disabled", "disabled");
});
$("input").keyup(function () { 
    $("#act").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#btn").prop("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: If it's a large amount of code create it as a plugin. If it is a library style function, put it in a library to call with appropriate parameter to select target etc. if it is a snippet (few lines) stop worrying :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie-Thanks :) I want to know it by general for e.g. if I've large amount of code...Im using MVC5 project...can you provide example...

Comment: For a large MVC 5 project I recommend using TypeScript too. It is then easier to use large amounts of JS in a structured way. Combine that with MVC *bundling* to produce efficient JS downloads. It all depends on what your code does/is as to how to split it up. You don't give much detail.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie-In MVC project you have folder of scripts,there I've two JS files which should Use the same code in some cases ,there is simple way to do somehow reuse instead of duplicate the code...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not optimal approach, but should work correctly in simpler projects. Create first file called common.js with code:

```
MyApp = {};
MyApp.Common = {};
MyApp.Common.initializeForms = function() {
    $("#act").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    $("form").change(function () { 
        $("#act").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#btn").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    $("input").keyup(function () { 
        $("#act").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#btn").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    });
}
```

`MyApp` is namespace of you application. `Common` namespace is used to store common function between modules.

Include this file in places, where this code is used and call by writing:

```
MyApp.Common.initializeForms();
```

Obviously there are more professional ways to do it, for example using `RequireJS` or another dependency injection library, but this approach works as well, specially if you bundle whole code in one file.